# Checkbox data handling

Tags: php, html, css, validation, checkbox

All. I'm currently trying to set a condition where after answering a form, the data, together with the selected/checked checkbox itself also, appears on the output/list of answers upon submission.

For example there are 3 checkboxes, if I choose Checkbox 1, that selected/checked checkbox together with the data also appears on the submitted form and cannot be altered.

Any idea/s or suggestion/s how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for this. You can add a function in onclick for a button and call the function to check the checkbox. Onclick of checkbox is given return false so that you cannot change the checkbox manually. The example is as follows:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="button" id="myButton" onClick="get_function()">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="Verified" onclick="return false;" required>
</form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
      function get_take_snap() {
document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}
```

After this if you want to add a data you can put a condition where if checkbox is checked then show the particular data.